# Ternary for setState multiple variables

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Tenary operator for Setstate

Is it possible to do this? I want for example set a variable containing the correct state to setState to.

```
 interface state {
    isfiltered: array<boolean>
 }

   this.setState({
        isFiltered: isFilteredCopy,
    });
}
```

I want to choose either isFiltered or languagesFilter, based on whether the state Array the function which is sent into, is the corresponding one.

Is it possible to also do multiple conditional ternary?

Like I got 4 options to choose based on condition in general?

The state containing all the boolean is array of boolean

If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: Yes you can do multiple ternaries and even chain them.

Comment: How can I do this? :)

Comment: Can you please copy here the code that you are trying?

Comment: @RaviRane I did now !

Comment: ternary chain goes somehting like this:

xpto ? xptz? : xpty :xpto

this means if the 1st is true then execute the 2nd ternary, if not just return xpto

Comment: isFilteredCopy how did you get this variable?

Comment: let isFilteredCopy = isFiltered.slice(); // Create a copy to avoid mutation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tried something like this:

```
myMethod(myCondition: boolean, isFilteredCopy: boolean[]) {
    const prop = myCondition ? "isFiltered" : "languagesFilter";
    this.setState({[prop]: isFilteredCopy});
}
```

you're going to have to use a type assertion:

```
myMethod(myCondition: boolean, isFilteredCopy: boolean[]) {
    const prop = myCondition ? "isFiltered" : "languagesFilter";
    this.setState({[prop]: isFilteredCopy} as any);
}
```

Here's [the open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948).